# I've divided a tkinter window into cells (using frame). How do I define a method that would apply to every cell?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I can't get a method I've created to apply to all the frames I've created in tkinter.

Working on Python 3.7. I've created a simple grid in tkinter using Frame and colored every cell by using Canvas. Now I want to use a method that will allow me to highlight a cell when hovering over it with my cursor, but when I do it only applies to the very last cell.

```
import tkinter as tk

BOARD_DIM = 7
CELL_DIM = 50
CELL_BORDER = 1

# Creating reference spots for the grid
x_coord = list(range(BOARD_DIM))
y_coord = list(range(BOARD_DIM))
grid_coord = []
for x in x_coord:
    for y in y_coord:
        grid_coord.append((x, y))

class Credence():
    """
    Class for the tkinter window
    """
    def __init__(self, window):
        self._window = window

        self._window.geometry(str(BOARD_DIM*CELL_DIM)+'x'+
                              str(BOARD_DIM*CELL_DIM))

        for loc in grid_coord:
            # Dividing the window into cells
            self._cell = tk.Frame(self._window, width=CELL_DIM, 
                                  height=CELL_DIM,
                                  highlightthickness=CELL_BORDER,
                                  name='(' + str(loc[0]) + ',' + 
                                  str(loc[1]) + ')')
            self._cell.place(x=loc[0] * CELL_DIM, y=loc[1] * CELL_DIM)
            self._picasso = tk.Canvas(self._cell, bg='Yellow')
            # Highlight a cell in red when hovering over it
            self._picasso.bind('<Enter>',
                               lambda event: self._picasso.config(bg = 
                               'Red'))
            self._picasso.bind('<Leave>',
                               lambda event: self._picasso.config(bg = 
                               'Yellow'))
            self._picasso.pack()
            # Drawing a circle in every cell
            self._circle = self._picasso.create_oval(CELL_BORDER+1,
                                                 CELL_BORDER+1,
                                                 CELL_DIM-(CELL_BORDER*2),
                                                 CELL_DIM-(CELL_BORDER*2))

window = tk.Tk()
Credence(window)
window.mainloop()
```

I expected the specific cell I'd hover over to change to red. In actuality only the bottom right cell does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the lambda, you're referencing `self._picasso`, but you're overwriting that on every iteration of the loop and it doesn't reference the canvas that generated the event.

So, you need to change:

```
        self._picasso.bind('<Enter>',
                           lambda event: self._picasso.config(bg = 
                           'Red'))
        self._picasso.bind('<Leave>',
                           lambda event: self._picasso.config(bg = 
                           'Yellow'))
```

To:

```
        self._picasso.bind('<Enter>',
                           lambda event: event.widget.config(bg = 
                           'Red'))
        self._picasso.bind('<Leave>',
                           lambda event: event.widget.config(bg = 
                           'Yellow'))
```

Also, there really is no point in keeping the last `_picasso` (or `_circle` or `_cell` for that matter) around as an object attribute, you're better off using a local variable, changing the solution to:

```
import tkinter as tk

BOARD_DIM = 7
CELL_DIM = 50
CELL_BORDER = 1

# Creating reference spots for the grid
x_coord = list(range(BOARD_DIM))
y_coord = list(range(BOARD_DIM))
grid_coord = []
for x in x_coord:
    for y in y_coord:
        grid_coord.append((x, y))

class Credence():
    """
    Class for the tkinter window
    """
    def __init__(self, window):
        self._window = window

        self._window.geometry(str(BOARD_DIM*CELL_DIM)+'x'+
                              str(BOARD_DIM*CELL_DIM))

        for loc in grid_coord:
            # Dividing the window into cells
            _cell = tk.Frame(self._window, width=CELL_DIM,
                                  height=CELL_DIM,
                                  highlightthickness=CELL_BORDER,
                                  name='(' + str(loc[0]) + ',' +
                                  str(loc[1]) + ')')
            _cell.place(x=loc[0] * CELL_DIM, y=loc[1] * CELL_DIM)
            _picasso = tk.Canvas(_cell, bg='Yellow')
            # Highlight a cell in red when hovering over it
            _picasso.bind('<Enter>',
                               lambda event: event.widget.config(bg =
                               'Red'))
            _picasso.bind('<Leave>',
                               lambda event: event.widget.config(bg =
                               'Yellow'))
            _picasso.pack()
            # Drawing a circle in every cell
            _circle = _picasso.create_oval(CELL_BORDER+1,
                                           CELL_BORDER+1,
                                           CELL_DIM-(CELL_BORDER*2),
                                           CELL_DIM-(CELL_BORDER*2))

window = tk.Tk()
Credence(window)
window.mainloop()
```

There's more style issues, but this seemed worth pointing out, as it contributed to your problem and possibly confusion.

Comment: Thanks a million. Yes style could definitely use some improvement, but just getting that part to work feels like a great accomplishment.